# Matlab; Scatter plot- shift the plot

Tags: matlab, scatter-plot

I use this code

```
 myfit = polyfit(R,E,1);
 r = polyval(myfit,R);
 plot(R, E, 'x');
 hold on;
 plot(R, r, '-');
 hold off;
```

So, I obtained this figure how to shift the points to right so that the x axis start from zero ?

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `axis` command:

```
>> axis([0 1 0 1]);
```

to set the limits of the axis (the range displayed).

See [`axis` doc](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axis.html) for more info.

Comment: I have such plot in each iteration, Do you know how to save each plot in each iteration? Thanks

Comment: @Fatime - you can use `getframe` to convert plot to image and write the image using `imwrite` to file. But if you want a more detailed answer - post this question as a new question